# Is there another way to cluster WSO2 IS servers aside from connecting to embedded-ldap on another node?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there another way to cluster WSO2 Identity Servers aside from connecting to another node's embedded-LDAP user store? I turn off embedded-LDAP anyway per other instructions. Would it be better to connect to another user's JDBC store instead?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0%2C+5.2.0+and+5.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the user stores is mandatory for the functionality of the cluster as both nodes of the cluster should be exposed to the same user base but the user store doesn't have to be the embedded LDAP. The embedded LDAP is usually used for development purposes. It is not recommended to use them in the production environment. So if your still in PoC stage, it is fine to point both nodes one embedded LDAP otherwise I recommend you to have an external user store such as LDAP, AD or a JDBC one.

You can either use an existing LDAP/AD or point to an outside JDBC user store. But both nodes should point to the same user store. You can refer [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Primary+User+Stores) for more information on configuring different types of user stores.

Comment: Thanks Lucifer. I think I know what you're talking about. How would node 1's shared store link to the its primary LDAP read-only store? Or would I need to link both nodes to the same primary LDAP read-only store and then have node 2 link to the node 1 shared store?

Comment: I'm not quire sure what you mean by the shared store. Basically, each IS node has it's own embedded LDAP and by default they are the primary user store of the nodes. If you want to set node 2's primary user store pointing to node 1's primary user store, in the user-mgt.xml of node 2, change the connection URL to node 1's URL and ignore the embedded LDAP in node 2. That way, both nodes will be having node 1's embedded LDAP as their primary user store.

Comment: The shared store would be Node 1's JDBC store that Node 2 would link to. I'm trying to move away from embedded-LDAP stores, but in doing so, I'm not sure if my primary read-only LDAP store on Node 1 would transfer information to the JDBC store which in turn would replicate to Node 2 or if I would need to specify the same primary read-only LDAP store on both nodes and link the Node 2 store to Node 1 to replicate any user transactions that occur with LDAP authentications. Thanks.